# How do i get a linebreak in a tikz / titlesec chapter style for a long chapter name

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec

i use a modified chapter style adapted from http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/fancy-chapter-tikz/

i tried to get a line break for a long chapter name with the `varwidth` package based on http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/4024/wie-kann-ich-in-einer-tikz-node-einen-zeilenumbruch-vornehmen (German!), but unfortunately i failed. can somebody please help me? how can i get chapter name on the left instead of right?

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
          rounded corners=10pt,inner sep=11pt,
          fill=black]
          {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
  };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}
```

i used my own colors in my report so i simply changed the color in this example to blue and black...

[image]

Comment: use `text width` option for example `\node[text width=5cm]` you can add option `align=left(center or right)`

Comment: Please always post a complete example people can *compile* to reproduce the output or error.

Comment: It is not wise to nest `tikzpicture` environments unless you absolutely cannot avoid it. (In that case, you hope it works as there's no alternative, but aren't surprised if it doesn't.)

Comment: `anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth` -> `anchor=west`. No idea what this has to do with the part of the question @touhami answered, mind you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the chapter title on the left side instead the right side use

```
    \node[
       anchor=west,% instead anchor=east
       xshift=.1\paperwidth,% instead xshift=.9\paperwidth
       ...]
      {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
```

And here is an example with the code from [Wie kann ich in einer TikZ Node einen Zeilenumbruch vornehmen?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/4024/wie-kann-ich-in-einer-tikz-node-einen-zeilenumbruch-vornehmen) that I have changed a little.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\newcommand\Umbruch[2][5cm]{\begin{varwidth}{#1}\raggedright\hspace*{0pt}#2\end{varwidth}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[fill=blue](current page.north east) 
      rectangle +(-\paperwidth,-2cm)coordinate(O);
    \node[anchor=west,xshift=.1\paperwidth,rectangle,
          rounded corners=10pt,inner sep=11pt,
          fill=black] at (O)
          {\color{white}\Umbruch{\chapterlabel#1}};
   \end{tikzpicture}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Einleitung}
Text
\chapter{Titel mit mehr Text}
\section{Section}
Text
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Test} test reference
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Note that there is now only one `tikzpicture` environment.

[image]

[image]

[image]